# Can you have an OR in a WHERE statement inside a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Is it possible to have an OR inside a WHERE statement in a mysql query as I have done below.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fields WHERE post_id=$id OR post_id="" order by id desc") or die(mysql_error());
```

This produces a server error when run on my site. Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ack, I won't be at the computer for the next 20 minutes or so, thus I won't be able to answer your questions.

Comment: Ah, turns out the error was because of the two instances of double quotes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

what are the errors.. as such ur query is fine but u string problems with all these double quotes.. try something like this..

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fields 
           WHERE post_id = " . $id . " OR post_id='' order by id desc") 
         or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: u may need to add single quotes around $id if its a string type like this..  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fields WHERE post_id = '" . $id . "' OR post_id='' order by id desc") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: -1 because post_id cannot be an int and a string at the same time.

Comment: @johan really after i put in a comment for that!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can have an OR. What is the type of `post_id`?

If post_id is a character type:

```
"SELECT * FROM fields WHERE post_id='$id' OR post_id='' order by id desc"
```

If it's an integer then it can't be equal to the empty string. Did you mean `post_id IS NULL` instead?

Answer (score 0):

What is the error? It looks like you have not escaped the double quote in the query. It should be:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fields WHERE post_id=$id OR post_id=\"\" order by id desc") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Either id is a string, in which case both instances need to be quoted, or it is an int, in which case it's still a good idea to have both instances quoted. But this code makes no sense, because an int can never be equal to `""`.

Comment: I should have used single quotes. And I think what I'll do is automatically have post_id equal 0 when it doesn't have a value instead of just leaving it empty. That should fix that problem.

Comment: @codedude: Why not use NULL when it doesn't have a value? That's what NULL is for.